# How do I agree a new element on a array after do a query?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to include a new element on a array that is filled with a query result.

For example, I have an array called $event with `$event['name']`, `$event['date']`, `$event['price']`.

Now, I want to add `$event['category']`. This one is not declared on DB event table, but $event is an array of my code. It not depends of the DB event table, no?

So... how I can put `$event['cateogory']` inside event in my Class code of `CodeIgniter`?

I tried to put it directly, and the error show that "category" index is not defined.

```
$events = $this->Event_model->get_all_events();
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $event['category'] = $this->Category_model->get_category($event['idCategory']);
    }
$data{
      'events' => $events,
}
$this->load->view('events_list',$data);
```

Thank you all

Comment: could you post your not working code..!

Comment: read up on using mysql "join" in Code Igniter. You're on the wrong path here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793807/codeigniter-php-mysql-retrieving-data-with-join

Comment: foreach makes a copy of the array, so changing a copy doesn't actually alter the original. To do that, you need to specifically alter the original like so: `foreach($events as $key=>$event) { $events[$key]['category'] = ...; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to iterate over every result and adding the category (*which you can do if you follow the comment made by [Tularis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3263885/tularis)*), you should let SQL add the category by using [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

In the [Code Igniter Documentation on Active Records](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), you'll find information about joining Tables in Code Igniter.

Here's a simple example from the documentation adjustet to your needs:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('events');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = events.idCategory');
$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces: 
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```